# Template expansion fails when passed Reference?

Tags: c++, templates, lua

I'm writing a simple wrapper around Lua's C Api, and having the functions take in a lua_State& instead of a pointer. However, when I try to pass a lua_State* value, I have to dereference it to pass by reference. The template that is expanded to has func sig that has the vm being passed in by value, not reference.

Since it is possible to use references and pointers of an object without its full definition, is there a way to convert from a pointer value to a referenced one with just a forward declaration of the type?

Edit:
After playing around with code a bit more. The dereferencing works for one of the function call but fails on another.

```
namespace Vm {

template<typename VM, typename T>
void push( VM vm, T value );

// If this function isn't here, push will fail too.
template<typename T>
void push( lua_State& luaState, T value ) {
    Vm::push( luaState, value );
}

template<>
void push( lua_State& luaState, double value ) {
    lua_pushnumber( &luaState, value );
}

template<typename VM>
void pop( VM vm, Uint32 nIndices );

template<>
void pop( lua_State& luaState, Uint32 nIndices ) {
    lua_pop( &luaState, nIndices );
}

}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    lua_State* luaState = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs( luaState );
    Vm::push( *luaState, (double)1.2f ); // This works fine.
    Vm::pop( *luaState, 1 ); // This generates error.
}
```

Compiler Error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct lua_State’
error: forward declaration of ‘struct lua_State’
error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Vm::pop(VM, Uint32) [with VM = lua_State; Uint32 = unsigned int]’
```

Comment: Which kind of cast are you using ?

Comment: What you describe should be fine; you shouldn't need a type definition to dereference a pointer and get a reference: http://ideone.com/yxrt94. Could you post some example code that gives the error?

Comment: I was looking for some sort of cast, but I just found reinterpret_cast<lua_State&>() which might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DanH. `reinterpret_cast` is unlikely to be what you're looking for: it's used for writing *unsafe* casts. `static_cast` is almost always better unless you know precisely what you're doing. However, as Mike Seymour points out, casting should not be necessary.

Comment: I take it you want your wrapper function to take lua_state& parm. Where do you have to dereference? If your wrapper functions can interact with each other, it should still be able to use reference variable. I think C++ wrapper function calling C lua function is okay, but not the other way around.

Comment: @syam: we should propose to deprecate `reinterpret_cast<...>()` and replace it by `this_is_not_the_cast_you_are_looking_for<...>()`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl `i_take_full_responsibility_of_whatever_bug_ensues<...>()` would be more of a deterrent I think. Responsibility scares people. ;)

Comment: By the way, that approach to Lua C API won't work nicely; trust me on that.

Comment: `-1` is of type `int`, or `signed int` to be specific. A conversion is required for `Uint32`. Since it's not an exact match, the specialization isn't chosen (pro-tip: function template specializations suck).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Maybe I'll take a look at your Api.

Comment: @Xeo Nice catch, I was using the function wrong, but thanks for tip.

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the definition of Vm::pop to have a reference attribute on the VM parameter seems to fix the problem:

```
namespace Vm {    
template<typename VM>
    void pop( VM& vm, Uint32 nIndices );
}
```

It wouldn't make any sense to make copies of the VM each time, unless you're a diehard functional programmer. I still don't get why the call resolved to lua_State and not lua_State&, and properly deduced in Vm::push wrapper function(This one managed to provide more info..somehow..). Oh-well, it's working nicely now.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

The relevant section is 5.3.1 [expr.unary.op] paragraph 1:

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to T,” the type of the result is “T.” [ Note: a pointer to an incomplete type (other than cv void) can be dereferenced. The lvalue thus obtained can be used in limited ways (to initialize a reference, for example); this lvalue must not be converted to a prvalue, see 4.1. —end note ]

That is, you can dereference a pointer to an incomplete type to get a reference to the incomplete type. You won't be able to do much with the thus obtained reference. Basically, you won't be able to do anything which requires the definition of the incomplete type.

Comment: Ok, so I'm not doing anything that requires the definition since I'm just passing it to Lua's Api which then uses its definition...

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a complete definition when using references, but you
also have some pass by value arguments when you instantiation your
templates with `VM` as `lua_State`.  And value parameters do require a
complete declaration at the call site and where the function is defined.

In your code, `Vm::push` is specialized for `lua_State&` and `double`,
so you get the specialization for `Vm::push( *luaState, (double)1.2f );`
(but why `(double)1.2f`, and not just `1.2`?), so you get the
specialization.  There is no specialization of `Vm::pop` for
`lua_State&` and `int`, however, so you get an instantiation of the
template, which uses pass by value.  (I am supposing that `Uint32` is
*not* a typedef for `int`.)

Comment: I added an explicit cast to Uint32, I guess I should have updated it here. If you look at the error, Vm::pop is resolved to (lua_State, Uint32), and doesn't have the reference attribute.